# Compound interest: why is there the exponential

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, exponential-function

In economy, it’s well known that compound interest at a constant interest rate provides exponential growth of the capital.

Why exponential though?

The general expression for the compound interest is just a geometric progression

If we call $r\in(0,1)$ the interest rate which applies after a time $t$, the capital as a discrete time function has the expression

$$C(nt)= C(0)(1+r)^n=C(0)\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}r^k$$

How is the exponential obtained in the continuum limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum accumulated after a period $t$ using an annual interest rate $r$ and a compounding frequency of $n$ (i.e. quarterly, monthly) on an initial capital $C_0$ is:

$$
C_t(n) = C_0 \bigg(1+\frac{r}{n}\bigg)^{nt}
$$

If the compunding frequency $n$ tends to infinity (we then imagine to compound infinitely often, i.e. continously) we have the exponential hrowth you mentioned. Indeed

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}C_t(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}C_0 \bigg(1+\frac{rt}{nt}\bigg)^{nt} = C_0 e^{rt}
$$

Comment: What makes you think that the, say, monthly rate $r$ *has to be* a twelfth of the corresponding annual one?

Comment: @ric.san simply by definition.

Comment: If a Bank gives you $ 100 $ percent interest every year or $ 50 $ percent every $6$ months, it's clearly not the same thing. And yet the interest $r$ over a time period $T$ is claimed to be *defined* as the interest $r/n$ over the time $T/n$. I don't understand really

Comment: @ric.san that's not what I defined. the time period is $t$, the payment frequency is $n$ and the *annual* rate is $r$. hence if the annual rate is $r=2\%$ then if I pay you every six months $n=2$, once a year $n=1$, quarterly $n=4$ and so on. the continuous compounding can be thought of as a payment every second for which $n$ is very large

Comment: What I don't understand is why you divide the annual rate by the payment frequency.

Comment: By definition: your formula I think uses what is called the effective interest rate, let's call it $r$. this is defined as if we compund annually, i.e. $r=(1+i/m)^m -1$ where $m$ is the frequency of payment and $i$ is the nominal rate (the one I used in my formula)